# Stata: why is my matrix not clearing over the foreach loop

Tags: for-loop, regression, stata

When I run the following code, the two output matrices (diffInDiffOne & diffInDiffTwo) are the same. My guess is that coeffs is not being replaced after each loop but I have no idea why . I think that the coefficients matrix is being overwritten but I have no idea how. I tried changing the for loop order but this surprisingly didn't solve my issue either:

```
local treatments treat_one treat_two
matrix diffInDiffOne = J(1,9,.)
matrix diffInDiffTwo = J(1,9,.)

foreach treatment in `treatments' {
    reg science inSchool#`treatment'#male
    matrix coeffs=e(b) 
    if treat_one==`treatment'{
       matrix diffInDiffOne = diffInDiffOne\coeffs
    }
    if treat_two==`treatment'{
       matrix diffInDiffTwo = diffInDiffTwo\coeffs
    }

}

 matrix list diffInDiffOne
 matrix list diffInDiffTwo
```

When I list the matrix they are both the same, depsite the fact that two regressions give different answers. Any help with this issue is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for adding the numbers after your signature. I was trying for a cosmetic edit and can't now omit them. Steve

Comment: This question would benefit from showing the actual results with a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code appears at first sight to reduce to

```
reg science inSchool#treat_one#male
matrix li e(b) 
reg science inSchool#treat_two#male 
matrix li e(b)
```

apart from the detail of adding nine missing values to the matrix.

However, that is not your code, so what is biting you? I guess at something much more subtle.

You should need to be very careful with the `if` command. Variables evaluated in `if` commands are evaluated in their first observation. So, the first time round the loop 
the conditions are

```
if treat_one[1] == treat_one[1]

if treat_two[1] == treat_one[1]
```

The second time, it is

```
if treat_one[1] == treat_two[1]

if treat_two[1] == treat_two[1]
```

If it is true in your data that `treat_one[1] == treat_two[1]` the effect will not be as you may imagine.

If you want to test for equality of strings, do something like

```
 if "`treatment'" == "treat_one"
```

You may have in mind something more like

```
foreach treatment in treat_one treat_two {
    reg science inSchool#`treatment'#male
    matrix `treatment' = e(b) 
    matrix list `treatment`
}
```

You seem to be wanting to write very complicated code for rather simple problems. A while back, I recommended thinking in terms of do-files rather than programs. That may be advice to reconsider.

Comment: There's also an unrelated issue that `inSchool#\`treatment'#male` fits _only_ the three-way interaction. If this is a difference-in-differences (DID) model, then the main effects and two-way interactions are required also. Perhaps you meant `##`. See the help for "factor variables".

Comment: The if issue that I was running into definitely had to do with comparing values instead of strings. I would like to be able to output the matrix to an excel document which is the reason why I am trying to save the outputs into a matrix. I used your method of saving the matrix as `treatment' but then I still need to figure out a way to save the information before it gets overridden by the next for loop. I could just add it to another matrix but that seems clunky. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can probably use stored results directly instead of saving new matrices. If you're using Stata 13, take advantage of `putexcel`; read `help putexcel`. There's also a nice blog entry here: http://blog.stata.com/2013/09/25/export-tables-to-excel/. If you're using Stata < 13, then read `help export` for some alternatives. See also user-written commands `estout` (Ben Jann at SSC) and `tabout` (Ian Watson at SSC). Use `ssc describe <command>` to take a look at those.

Comment: I focused on what I presumed was your bug. Looking at the problem in the large, however, Stata matrices don't purport to be multipurpose tables, and you are likely to be better off looking at previous programs such as those named by @RobertoFerrer.